# *ngFor subarray object - Angular + Firebase

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I am trying to use a simple `ngFor` but I am dealing with one problem.

**Object**

```
export class Post {
  $key: string;
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
  postedBy: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  paragraphs: [] = [];
}
```

my intention is to use the following `HTML` code:

```
<p *ngFor="let p of databaseService.selectedPost[0].paragraphs">a</p>
```

meaning that I want to show one paragraph per paragraph of my object but I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

I have tried to use `console.log(this.selectedPost[0].paragraphs.p1);` being `p1` there first of my paragraphs and it actually works but I am not able to do it from `HTML` (it has p1, p2, p3.. as names). The next picture shows the `console.log`

[image]

This is the object in the database:

[image]

How could I do it?

Comment: databaseService.selectedPost[0].paragraphs should be array. Is it?

Comment: I would say that it is an array, I have updated the question

Comment: Please check if your data is array inside array or two connected arrays. You need to treat them as such

Comment: The data is what is how the picture shows. First an array (1 would be the 1st post of the array) and inside of this array you have some elements, including "paragraphs" what I guess it is another array (where p1, p2, p3 are the elements)

Comment: If these are connected arrays you can try something like first access the top array and then access the actual array you want. So you need to nest ngFor in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of things, `databaseService.selectedPost[0].paragraph` is an object, as you said, you can directly access `p1`.

> I have tried to use console.log(this.selectedPost[0].paragraphs.p1); being p1 there first of my paragraphs and it actually works

If that is the case, you can use Angular's [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to iterate through with an `*ngFor`

A working example would look like:

```
<p *ngFor="let paragraph of databaseService.selectedPost[0].paragraphs | keyvalue">{{ paragraph.value }}</p>
```

Comment: This almost works but it does not. If I write "<p *ngFor="let paragraph of databaseService.selectedPost[0].paragraphs | keyvalue">Hello</p>" it writes 6 times a paragraph with "Hello", but I am not able to access to the variable. Using {{paragraph}} shows "[object Object]" and if I try {{p1}} it shows nothing

Comment: sure, so a `paragraph` is an object too, it will have attributes. Do you know what the structure of it looks like? for example, if there is a property `text` on the object `paragraph` you can insert `{{ paragraph.text }}` into the HTML (just an example)

Comment: it is what I am trying. The structure of the whole object is in the question. In the paragraph array you have p1, p2, p3, p4... but trying to use {{paragraph.p1}} fails

Comment: Please see my updated HTML snippet, i am now doing `{{ paragraph.value }}`

Comment: Brilliant, glad i could help :)!